# How to map 2+ tables to an entity in .NET Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Using the designer in Visual Studio, how can you define an entity that maps to 2 or more tables?

Comment: 1 entity with properties stored in 2 or more tables or 1 entity with relationships to 2 or more tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [Entity Framework map multiple tables to one entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772064/entity-framework-map-multiple-tables-to-one-entity)

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716698.aspx