# How to map 2+ entities to same table in .NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create 2 entities that operate as different views on the same underlying db table.  When I create these in Visual Studio's entity model and place an association between them, I get a "Association is not mapped" error.  I read an article (http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx) that describes how to hand-code the XML in the edmx to add a ReferentialConstraint but that didn't help me any.

Any thoughts?  Does the designer not support this?

Comment: Duplicate, same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543604/how-to-map-2-tables-to-an-entity-in-net-entity-framework

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. Basically I have "FooTable" that I would like to represent as "Bar" and "Fu" entities based upon FooTable.FooType

Comment: jcm - I gave up on this.  I'm pretty sure the designer does not support this.

Comment: Craig - this is not a duplicate.  my other question is for the vice-versa scenario.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, I'd guess that there wasn't an Association created for the storage schema in the edmx (the SSDL of the edmx XML).  A conceptual association has been created if you can see it in the designer, but there's no storage definition behind the scenes.  I'm guessin'.  =)