# How to change an Entity source table after the context is created?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the same problem I explained at [Change entity map to another "unknown" table at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142530/change-entity-map-to-another-unknown-table-at-runtime) but now I need it after the context is created. I'm using Code First with EF version 4.1. Do I have to create again the entire context?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/08/27/changing-table-names-in-an-orm.aspx) may be useful in mapping to different tables during runtime.

Edit: [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2008/07/23/linq-to-sql-dynamic-mapping.aspx) may also come in handy.